# How do I use nohup and tail it in one command

Tags: shell, nohup

Instead of:

```
  nohup ./script.sh &
  tail -f nohup.out
```

I want to do:

```
nohup ./script.sh &; tail -f nohup.out
```

but it doesn't work because you have to press return after callng nohup.

Comment: @iruvar that doesnt work

Comment: I have difficulties to reproduce your problem. The two lines should be equivalent to one line `nohup ./script.sh & tail -f nohup.out`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Apart from the error with the consecutive `&;` characters that prevents the second example from working, I can't see any real difference between your two examples.

Comment: (VPfB,roamia) Except there's a race; typing `nohup whatever &` then typing `tail -f nohup.out` allows `nohup` time to create `nohup.out` before `tail` looks for it; `nohup ... & tail ...` starts the processes 'simultaneously' and the `tail` may find `nohup.out` missing and quit. Paul: try `touch nohup.out; nohup whatever & tail -f nohup.out`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That race condition is in the original command sequence as well. Imagine that it is not typed, but executed in a script.

Comment: i just want it one one line so easier to copy and paste steps. Its a process I have to do once a month consisting of about 20 steps, I cant put all steps in single script because need to check output for unexpected errors due to changes outside of my control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash`, `dash` and `pdksh`, the `&` terminates the command line `nohup ./script.sh`, so you can't have `;` after it.

With `;`, you'll get

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

just like you'll get if you try to execute the command `;` by itself.

In `ksh93` and `zsh` your command works just fine as is.

For `bash` and those other shells, do this instead:

```
$ nohup ./script.sh & tail -f nohup.out
```

Be aware though, that just as when running a pipeline, the different parts of the pipeline are initiated (more or less) at the same time. If `tail` happens to start befor the file `nohup.out` exists, it will fail with something like

```
tail: nohup.out: No such file or directory
```

To work around this:

```
$ nohup ./script.sh & sleep 1 && tail -f nohup.out
```

or, if you don't like waiting for a second:

```
$ nohup ./script.sh & while ! test -f nohup.out; do :; done && tail -f nohup.out
```

or, as "VPfB" points out in the comments below,

```
$ nohup ./script.sh >output & tail -f output
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest `nohup cmd > outfile & tail -f outfile`

Comment: ``tail -F`` will retry until the file is there so you can skip the ``sleep``.

Comment: okay that works fine, thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Oh damn it doesnt work, but if I cntl -C to get out of the tail -f (because I might want to do something else) it seems to stop the nohup as well

Answer (score 0):

Simulate the return key before running nohup:

```
echo -e "\n" | nohup ./script.sh & tail -f nohup.out
```

example script:

```
[$]› cat tmp1.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done
```

result:

```
[$]› echo -e "\n" | nohup ./tmp1.sh & tail -f nohup.out
[3] 25402
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

[3]   Done                    echo -e "\n" | nohup ./tmp1.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. "&;" might be the error.

```
nohup ./script.sh & tail -f nohup.out
```

But if tail is too fast to start :

```
nohup ./script.sh & sleep 1 ; tail -f nohup.out
```